# Domain Controller not Syncing with Networked PCs

Tags: dns, controller

I have got this problem where two PC's on a network are not syncing with the domain controller in my organisation. Therefore user names and password are not working on these specific PCs, Therefore denying access to these PCs both through standard users and admin users.

I am now suspecting these two PCs are just plain not picking up the existence of the domain controller. Now I am sure if we can somehow get access to these PCs to manually configure the DNS IP on these user PCs we can point to the domain controller IP and this should fix the problem.

So my question, is there a possible solution to get access to these PCs while they do not recognize the domain controller?

PS: I have also tried resetting these users and their passwords on the active directory server.

I am hoping this issues can be resolved fairly quickly. if you need more information just let me know what you need to know, sorry I am kind if in the dark here on this one.

Cheers looking forward to hearing the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of information missing...

1. Did these PCs ever work correctly?
2. Are these PCs joined to the AD domain?
3. Has the configuration on any DHCP servers invovled changed?
4. What IPs are they pointing to for DNS service currently?

Many more possible questions based on answers to those.

You should still be able to use remote desktop to get to them, probably have to use IP address, if that is/was enabled while they were still able to reach the DCs.  (but that assumes (1) yes, (2) yes )